# npm run serve vs build

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

In my Vue JS application I have a file called `.env.individual` which defines a variable use for making API calls to the backend.

I also have `.env` and `.env.production`, etc, all with different values for the API URL variable.

When I run `npm run serve -- --mode individual` the application starts up and uses the URL found in the `.env.individual` file. Likewise, when I run `npm run serve -- --mode production` the application starts up and uses the variable found in the `.env.production` file.

Given the above I was assuming that when I run `npm run build -- --mode individual` the `\dist` would be generated and I could then run `npm run serve` and the application would use the variables found in the `.env.individual` file.

Given my `package.json` file contains this:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "deploy": "vue-cli-service s3-deploy",
    "release": "npm run build && npm run deploy"
},
```

What is `npm run serve` actually doing and why - when I want to use a specific `.env.XXX` file do I need to specify it exactly?

Comment: `serve` is the _dev_ server, which isn't the same thing as serving the `dist/` outputs: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve.

Answer (score 2):

`npm run serve` does not run your application from `/dist` folder. It compiles unoptimized build in memory (RAM). If you want run your optimized build from `/dist` folder, you can run it by some http server. For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server .